# Visual Studio 2005: All projects in solution explorer expanded on first opening of solution

Tags: visual-studio

Is any way to tell the solution explorer of Visual Studio 2005 not to expand all projects on the first opening of the solutio after svn-checkout?

Edit:
Thanks for pointing out the PowerCommands. As I am using Visual Studio 2005 with .Net 2.0 it does not work for me. Are there similar tools available for VS2005?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074/visual-studio-open-files-question#16079). Solution is to delete the .suo file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: something like PowerPack: [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/) has a solution collapse option too, and it works with 2005.

I configure it to collapse "Top Items Only" because "All Projects and Files" works too slowly and flickery for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found this annoying too, so my solution was to install [PowerCommands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) for Visual Studio which is a nice add in, it has "Colapse Project" function which does exactly that.
it also has a dozen of other cool features.

Highly recommended.

Comment: Seems like PowerCommands are only available for VisualStudio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

My default (without anyway of changing this as far as I know) VS will expand all the projects like that on first opening of a solution and creation of the solution user options file. as **ljubomir** mentioned, the best thing to do is create something to collapse all the projects.