# Visual Studio 2010 Express no longer saves open tabs when closing solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. I've been using it for a few months without any problems. About a week ago, it stopped saving my open tabs when I close Visual Studio. The next time I open the solution, it does not automatically open the files I had open when I last closed the solution. I'm not sure why it stopped working and I can't find the setting that controls this. Has anyone else run into this? If so, how did you get it to remember your open tabs again?

Comment: I could have sworn there was a setting for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: Sorry, there is no setting for that.. It could be some issue either with saving .suo file in the solution folder or there could be a macro defined for SolutionEvents.BeforeClosing event - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074/visual-studio-open-files-question

Comment: It could be an add-in that you've installed.  But if you do find what it is please post because I actually want this functionality.

Comment: Definitely not an add-in. This is VS 2010 Express, which doesn't allow add-ins.

Comment: I'd guess at the .suo file as well.  Don't check it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to fix it, but a fresh install works correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Show hidden files in solution folder in windows explorer and you will find visual studio *.suo file (it contains user related information). Delete it, after opening solution next time it will be recreated. Seems that sometimes there are problems with this file (for example you take this file from another user's machine via source control(by the way: DO NOT PUT IT INTO SOURCE CONTROL!)); this causes not only "not opening previous tabs", but other confusing things as well, like not be able to save "startup" project between visual studio restarts.

Even typical `.ignore` file for source control suggests **NOT** to add it:

```
[Bb]in
*.user
*.suo
*.[Cc]ache
*.bak
*.ncb
*.log
*.pdb
*.DS_Store
[Tt]humbs.db 
_ReSharper.*
*.resharper
Ankh.NoLoad
```

Comment: Open solution, THEN delete the suo file, close solution. FIXED. Thanks I had this issue for months with just one of my applications , the others were fine. Much obliged for your answer. THANK YOU

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. What I did to solve:

- Tools > Import and Export Settings
- - Export your current settings but without 'General > Window Layouts'

Reset your settings via:

> - Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings

Through the same menu, import your previously exported settings. That fixed the issue for me, hope it helps who gets it next.